# Ending this sentence with a "to"

Tags: prepositions

> To that great man, I dedicate this book to.

Is this correct? I'm wondering if it's alright to end a sentence with a to proposition at the end.

Comment: Welcome to ELL. It's not very clear what you're asking here; why would you use a preposition twice arbitrarily like this? What's wrong with *To that great man, I dedicate this book*?

Answer (score 1):

You can have either of the *to*'s, but not both; but the meaning is different.

> To that great man, I dedicate this book.

is a perfectly good sentence. It's a non-standard word order (more normal would be "I dedicate this book to that great man") so it has the effect of emphasising the great man.

> That great man I dedicate this book to.

(preferably without the comma) is a sentence fragment: there is an implied relative pronoun "That great man that/who/whom I dedicate this book to", so the fragment is a complex noun phrase, not a whole sentence. To make it a whole sentence you need a main verb:

> That great man I dedicate this book to is John Smith.

But in a suitable conversational context, a sentence fragment like that can stand on its own.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the second *to* is wrong because the sentence already has one (at the beginning).

In the past, prepositions at the end of the sentence are termed "stranded prepositions" and regarded as a stylistic flaw, if not even grammatically wrong. More modern linguists and style guides, however, regard them as something that's perfectly permissible.

[Source:](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2011/11/grammar-myths-prepositions/)

Personally, prepositions at the end of a sentence are nothing I object **to**. Ba-dum-tsss!

Comment: "Stranded prepositions" are "perfectly permissible" only in three or four very specific grammatical constructions. You can't end just any sentence with.